# axisLabelDistance attribute is not working when i use rotateLabels to rotate the ticks on x-axis with angular nvd3

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am using a simple line chart using angular nvd3, i am using dates as ticks on x-axis and i want some space between ticks and axis label. For that i use `axisLabelDistance: 100,` to maintain the gap, and it is working fine. My problem is when i use `rotateLabels: 15` to rotate the x-axis ticks then `axisLabelDistance` is stopped working.

Here is example [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1OXXJg3FDZxxmTbTfWU?p=preview)

I need some more gap between the ticks and the axis label.
Thanks